# how to keep track gnome extensions download and install progress?

Tags: fedora, gnome, gnome3, firefox, gnome-shell

For example, I open Firefox and then turn on **Transparent Windows** at [Transparent Windows Extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/684/transparent-windows/)

[image]

But how do I know when it will complete downloading and installing? There's no notification or progress indicator. I visit https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ and also press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> keys but haven't found anything.

My platform is Fedora 21 and gnome 3.14.2

**[UPDATE]** Follow this [instruction](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028/how-to-make-a-window-transparent-in-gnome), I have to manually download [zip](https://github.com/saysilence/transparentwindows) file, unzip it and `cp -r 'transparentwindows@ellen/metadata.json' ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/`, edit transparentwindows@ellen/metadata.json's "shell-version" to add my current version "3.14". Then `gnome-session-quit` logout and login again. Open https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ with Firefox will now allow me to turn on **Transparent Windows** extension.

But still it's not my exact question, I'm curious about the official way to keep track of the download progress and installation fail log if any.

Answer (score 1):

Download and install time should be just a few seconds.  Once it shows up in [Installed Extensions](https://extensions.gnome.org/local/), the extension is installed and you're good to go.

If it doesn't, check your browser window: there might be a Firefox pop-up saying something like "Firefox prevented this site to install software on your computer".  In this case, click on Allow to authorize the changes.

Comment: I don't why but it's seems like failed to install because i keep getting "off" status after press F5 to refresh the extension page. I tried other extension but no such problem. Is there any error/progress log i can check ? No such "Firefox prevented..." pop-up.